# Robotframework accept website's term of service

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I wish to automate my [www.tori.fi](https://www.tori.fi/) browsing using robotframework. My biggest problem thus far is to get the robot to click on the "Hyväksy kaikki evästeet"- button. Simple Xpath targetting won't do, as it does not find the element. The popup is obsctructicating the website.

I tried this:

```
Click Element    //*[@id="notice"]/div[6]/button[2]
```

But the result was:

```
Element with locator '//*[@id="notice"]/div[6]/button[2]' not found
```

[Image of the websites TOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOFDx.png)

I am on Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we find an overlay, we should suspect of it being inside a frame. This is the case in the site under testing.

Here is a complete working test suite:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Click button in frame
    Open Browser    https://www.tori.fi/    firefox
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Select Frame    //iframe[@title="SP Consent Message"]
    ${button}=    Get WebElement    //button[@title="Hyväksy kaikki evästeet"]
    Click Element    ${button}
    Unselect Frame
    Sleep    5 seconds
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Close All Browsers
```

Comment: That indeed does it, thanks.